# Cypress Drag and drop script issue

Tags: drag-and-drop, cypress

I am struggling to test drag and drop with Cypress.Try lot of commands but not getting the success and even not getting the any error.Please provide the solution for that.

1.Also added import '@4tw/cypress-drag-drop' in command.js and try below

```js
cy.get('#playlist-48').drag("div[id='dtmf-1'] div[class='flex-grow-1 text-overflow-ellipsis']");
```

2.script

```js
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer;

        cy.get('#playlist-49')
            .trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer });

        cy.get('#dtmf-1')
            .trigger('drop', { dataTransfer });

        cy.get('#playlist-49')
            .trigger('dragend');
```

3.Script

```js
cy.get('#playlist-49').trigger('mousedown', {which: 1}); 
cy.get('#dtmf-1').trigger('mousemove').trigger('mouseup', {force:true})
```

4.script

```js
const draggable = cy.get('#playlist-49')
const target = cy.get('#dtmf-1')
    
    // Perform drag and drop operation
    draggable.trigger('dragstart', { button: 0 })
    target.trigger('mousemove')
    draggable.trigger('mouseup', { force: true })
    
    // Assert that the element was dropped successfully
    cy.get('#dtmf-playlist-1-49').should('have.text', 'opgemm45')
```

Try above all different solution but did't get the success

Comment: Do you maybe have an example website where we could try this out? I was struggling to get drag and drop to work with canvas, but I guess the implementation depends on the website that you test and how they implemented the drag and drop feature. It could be using drag events or using mouse events or both.

Comment: Maybe provide an example of your website's HTML structure. It's also possible that your drag-and-drop element is contained within an iframe.